# How to reset Firebird 3.0 identity column

Tags: firebird, identity-column, firebird-3.0

I am using Firebird 3 for my project and I added identity columns for auto-increment columns.

Before publishing it, I tested the database with thousands of records now I want to reset the column back to zero but I couldn't find any solution.

Here is the image
[image]

Comment: You should consider not using a production database for testing (or vice versa: not using a test database for production work), you have potentially left testdata behind. Consider recreating the database anew.

Comment: "Here is the image" - if unknown program which translates into Firebird SQL commands in an unknown way...

Comment: @Arioch, its screenshot from firebird maestro.

Comment: What if you would uncheck the `Primary Key` checkbox and save the field?

Comment: @Arioch'The AFAIK, the field will not `primary key` anymore.

Comment: sure, but would after that Maestro permit you to reset counter once the field is no more PK ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Firebird 3 release notes](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html) on [identity columns](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-ddl-identity):

> ```
> <alter column definition> ::=
>     <name> RESTART [ WITH <value> ]
> ```
>
> A column definition can be altered to modify the starting value of the generator. `RESTART` alone resets the generator to zero;
> the optional `WITH <value>` clause allows the restarted generator to
> start at a value other than zero.

For more information, see also ticket [CORE-4206](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-4206).

In other words, to restart the identity sequence, you can use

```
alter table yourtable alter column idcolumn restart
```

Where `yourtable` should be the name of your table, and `idcolumn` the name of the identity column that needs to be reset.

I don't know which tool you show in the screenshot, but apparently it doesn't support this option in its user interface. That means you'll need to execute the DDL statement shown above directly. Consider filing an improvement request with the maintainer of that tool if you think it is important.